# How to use a string value in foreach?

Tags: powershell

How to use a string value in foreach?

The following works.

```
$printString='$_.name+","+$_.name'
Get-ChildItem|foreach {$_.name+','+$_.name}
```

**But the following doesn't work**

```
Get-ChildItem|foreach {$printString}
```

But I need it to work: because I have a task to print each column in a table, I can use table dictionary to get all the columns, so all are dynamic, and then when I try to print the result, I also use a string like above to print the result. Any solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several solutions. Some of them that came on my mid are:

```
$printString='$($_.name),$($_.name)'
Get-ChildItem | % { $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($printString) }

$formatString='{0},{0}'
Get-ChildItem | % { $formatString -f $_.Name }

$s = {param($file) $file.Name + "," + $file.Name }
Get-ChildItem | % { & $s $_ }
```

The first one expands string and that's probably what you wanted. Note that composed variables  have to be enclosed in `$(..)`. The second just formats some input. The third uses scriptblock there you can create any string you want (the most powerfull)

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
 $printString={$_.name+","+$_.name}
 Get-ChildItem |foreach {.$printString}
```

Comment: it works!! but please help me understand it: $pirntString is a script block, but what's the meaning of dot in "foreach {.$printString}"?

Comment: The dot executes the scriptblock in the current scope.

Comment: You could have also left out the braces in the foreach clause.  "Get-ChildItem | foreach $printString" would also work.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
$printString='$_.name+","+$_.name'
Get-ChildItem|foreach { Invoke-Expression $printString }
```

Comment: it also works, and what's the difference between Invoke-Expression  and ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString?, looks them they work in the same way?

Comment: They're actually quite different.  ExpandString expands the variables and expressions in a string, producing a new string.  Invoke-Expression executes a string as though it were a PowerShell command.  You'll note that $printString is defined differently in the two examples.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting possibility:

```
dir | select @{Name='Name'; Expression={$_.Name, $_.Name}}
```